# How to get coordinates

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, contentoffset

I have UIWebView for displaying HTML contents. I'm getting touch coordinates from UIWebView using Longpress gesture. If i get coordinate value from UIWebView x = 146.5 and y = 230.67. I stored these value to database. Later when i load the UIWebView i'm getting these value from database. If these values match i need to go 146.5 and 230.67. While the webview i can able to go that point. But the problem is, my webview is 320x568. If i use setContentOffset: my webview size appear 146.5x230.67 instead of 320x568. I need to display webview is 320x568 but i can visit 146.5x230.67 point. Is it possbile?

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{


float bx=[xv floatForKey:@"xvalue"];


    float by=[yv floatForKey:@"yvalue"];


     NSString  *savedValue = [prefs stringForKey:@"got"];



 if(savedValue){



            [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(bx, by)];

 }



    }

}
```

bx,by is the x and y coordinate value coming from database.

Comment: I make a test on my webview demo like this: -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 300)];       
} it works well.Please paste some code for deep analyze

Comment: what? I didn't undertand

Comment: my comment is updated

Comment: Got it if i use  [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, by)]; It's working.. thanks

Comment: Can you post your answer. I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a test on my webview demo like this:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 300)]; }
```

it works well.Please paste some code for deep analyze